# Query Performance too Slow

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

Im having performance issues with this query. If I remove the status column it runs very fast but adding the subquery in the column section delays way too much the query 1.02 min. How can I modify this query so it runs fast getting the desired data.

The reason I put that subquery there its because I needed the status for the latest activity, some activities have null status so I have to ignore them.

Establishments: 6.5k rows -
EstablishmentActivities: 70k rows - 
Status: 2 (Active, Inactive)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    est.id,
    est.trackingNumber,
    est.NAME AS 'establishment',
    actTypes.NAME AS 'activity',
    (
        SELECT stat3.NAME
        FROM SACPAN_EstablishmentActivities eact3
        INNER JOIN SACPAN_ActivityTypes at3
            ON eact3.activityType_FK = at3.code
        INNER JOIN SACPAN_Status stat3
            ON stat3.id = at3.status_FK
        WHERE eact3.establishment_FK = est.id
          AND eact3.rowCreatedDT = (
            SELECT MAX(est4.rowCreatedDT)
            FROM SACPAN_EstablishmentActivities est4
            INNER JOIN SACPAN_ActivityTypes at4
                ON est4.establishment_fk = est.id
                AND est4.activityType_FK = at4.code
            WHERE est4.establishment_fk = est.id
              AND at4.status_FK IS NOT NULL
          )
          AND at3.status_FK IS NOT NULL
    ) AS 'status',
    est.authorizationNumber,
    reg.NAME AS 'region',
    mun.NAME AS 'municipality',
    ISNULL(usr.NAME,  '') + ISNULL(+ ' ' + usr.lastName,  '')
        AS 'created',
    ISNULL(usr2.NAME, '') + ISNULL(+ ' ' + usr2.lastName, '')
        AS 'updated',
    est.rowCreatedDT,
    est.rowUpdatedDT,
    CASE WHEN est.rowUpdatedDT >= est.rowCreatedDT
         THEN est.rowUpdatedDT
         ELSE est.rowCreatedDT
    END AS 'LatestCreatedOrModified'
FROM SACPAN_Establishments est
INNER JOIN SACPAN_EstablishmentActivities eact
    ON est.id = eact.establishment_FK
INNER JOIN SACPAN_ActivityTypes actTypes
    ON eact.activityType_FK = actTypes.code
INNER JOIN SACPAN_Regions reg
    ON est.region_FK = reg.code --
INNER JOIN SACPAN_Municipalities mun
    ON est.municipality_FK = mun.code
INNER JOIN SACPAN_ContactEstablishments ce
    ON ce.establishment_FK = est.id
INNER JOIN SACPAN_Contacts con
    ON ce.contact_FK = con.id
--JOIN SACPAN_Status stat ON stat.id = actTypes.status_FK
INNER JOIN SACPAN_Users usr
    ON usr.id = est.rowCreatedBy_FK
LEFT JOIN SACPAN_Users usr2
    ON usr2.id = est.rowUpdatedBy_FK
WHERE (con.ssn = @ssn OR @ssn = '*')
  AND eact.rowCreatedDT = (
    SELECT MAX(eact2.rowCreatedDT)
    FROM SACPAN_EstablishmentActivities eact2
    WHERE eact2.establishment_FK = est.id
)
--AND est.id = 6266
ORDER BY 'LatestCreatedOrModified' DESC
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Update your answer with the execution plan.

Comment: That might be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a temporary table and creating an index to it, this removed the need of the slow subquery in the select statement. Then I join the temp table as I do with normal tables.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving that 'activiy' query to a Left Join and see if it speeds it up.